# Joining two SQL query results on specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that work good. They have different columns (different names) except one column 'client_id'.
I want to join these two queries on that column 'client_id'.
I have tried with `union` and with `join` but it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?

```
   (SELECT i_data.client_id, 
           SUM(i_data.like_by_post) AS total_likes, 
           SUM(i_data.comment_by_post) AS total_comments
      FROM instagram_data AS i_data
  GROUP BY i_data.client_id)
INNER JOIN  
   (SELECT ig_profile.client_id, ig_profile.username, 
           ig_profile.counts_media AS total_posts, 
           ig_profile.followed_by AS followers
      FROM instagram_profile AS ig_profile
  GROUP BY ig_profile.client_id
  ORDER BY ig_profile.current_date) 
        ON i_data.client_id = ig_profile.client_id
```

Comment: Union all and INNER Joins are for different purpose. Inner join will combine data in one row per matched key. On the other hand Union All will add rows from both table in one result set. which one you really wants? BTW, if you are looking for INNER join, you missing the SELECT * FROM at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a join:

```
select * from (
  select i_data.client_id, sum(i_data.like_by_post) as total_likes, 
    sum(i_data.comment_by_post) as total_comments
  from instagram_data as i_data
  group by i_data.client_id
) d inner join (
  select ig_profile.client_id, ig_profile.username, 
    ig_profile.counts_media as total_posts, ig_profile.followed_by as followers
  from instagram_profile as ig_profile
  group by ig_profile.client_id
  order by ig_profile.current_date
) p
on d.client_id = p.client_id
```

Replace * with the columns that you want to select.
Also the order by clause in the 2nd query is useless and you can remove it. You must sort the result as you want.
 
Since the 2 queries do not return the same number of columns (with the same data types) you can't use UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not right.

Please try below query :

```
        SELECT i_data.client_id, 
           SUM(i_data.like_by_post) AS total_likes, 
           SUM(i_data.comment_by_post) AS total_comments,
           ig_profile.client_id, ig_profile.username, 
           ig_profile.counts_media AS total_posts, 
           ig_profile.followed_by AS followers 
      FROM instagram_data AS i_data  
INNER JOIN instagram_profile AS ig_profile 
        ON i_data.client_id = ig_profile.client_id 
  GROUP BY i_data.client_id,ig_profile.client_id 
  ORDER BY ig_profile.current_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the alias name for both queries then join them your code will be like this;

```
select i_data.client_id, sum(i_data.like_by_post) as total_likes, sum(i_data.comment_by_post) as total_comments from instagram_data as i_data inner join(select client_id, username, counts_media as total_posts, followed_by as followers from instagram_profile group by client_id order by current_date) as ig_profile on i_data.client_id = ig_profile.client_id group by i_data.client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select i_data.client_id, sum(i_data.like_by_post) as total_likes, sum(i_data.comment_by_post) as total_comments, 
ig_profile.client_id, ig_profile.username, ig_profile.counts_media as total_posts, ig_profile.followed_by as followers

from instagram_data as i_data
left join instagram_profile as ig_profile on i_data.client_id = ig_profile.client_id

group by ig_profile.client_id,  i_data.client_id
order by ig_profile.current_date
```

You can revert to your inner join as it meets your demand.